# Jquery Datepicker Inline with alternating inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to set up an inline DatePicker that will update a #StartDate altField on select and then on the next select it will update the #EndDate altField.

So, it uses the same inline calendar to update what is essentially a date range with two inputs. There seem to be a lot of resources around on this but none are concerning an inline datepicker.

I'm struggling with getting the second altField to update. Every select just updates the first  altField.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onSelect event handler to update the datepicker's altField each time a date is selected:

```
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            inline:true,
            altField: "#startDate",
            onSelect: function(date, ui){
                ui.settings.altField = (ui.settings.altField=="#startDate") ? "#endDate" : "#startDate";
            }
        });
```

I would be careful about how you use this though. This seems like it could easily make for a confusing UI.